# How to call GWT client code from within a GQuery event handler?

Tags: gwt, errai, gquery

I'm learning GQuery. It seems cool, but also a little confusing.

I have the following GWT client code. The selected item fades out, nicely. But the `delete` method never gets called. There is no error. It's very odd.

Is it even possible to call non-GQuery functions from inside a GQuery method?

```
delete.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        $(myIndicator).fadeOut(500, new Function(){
            @Override
            public void f() {                       
                super.f();
                delete();
            }                   
        });                 

    }
});
```

And the `delete` method is:

```
private void delete() {
    removeFromParent();
    ruleDeleteRequestEvent.fire(new RuleDeleteRequestEvent(ruleBinder.getModel()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call `super.f()`, if so the default implementation of `Function.f()` will throw an Exception preventing the next line be executed ([take a look to the source code](https://github.com/gwtquery/gwtquery/blob/master/gwtquery-core/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/query/client/Function.java#L333)) .